# Call a C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

The problem is that i've got a C++ DLL that I want to use in my C# project.

The problematic function has the prototype:

```
 int MRK3LINK_Open(void (*pfLog)(const char* s),void (*pfErrorOut)(const char* s));
```

The documentation states that:

- pfLog is a pointer to log handler function of type const char*.
- pfErrorOut is a pointer to error out handler function of type const char*.

And an example of how to call the functions of the DLL from C++:

```
static void _LogHandler(const char* sLog) {
   printf(sLog);
}

static void _ErrorOutHandler(const char* sError) {
   MessageBox(NULL, sError, "2-Link", MB_OK);
}

MRK3LINK_Open(_LogHandler, _ErrorOutHandler);
```

I'm stuck on this for 2 days now. Could you provide me some tips ?

Thanks.

Comment: Two probable bugs, you didn't post nearly enough.  You probably forgot the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute on the delegate declaration to ensure that the CLR knows that this is a CallingConvention.Cdecl function pointer.  And you are not storing the delegate objects anywhere so they are going to get garbage collected, crashing the program when the C code makes the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The two parameters are function pointers. They will map to delegates in C++. Like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void LogHandlerDelegate(string str);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void ErrorOutHandlerDelegate(string error);
```

Then the function you import is:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int MRK3LINK_Open(
    LogHandlerDelegate LogHandler,
    ErrorOutHandlerDelegate ErrorOutHandler
);
```

Then you create delegates in the usual way and pass them to `MRK3LINK_Open`. Make sure that you store references to the delegates if the unmanaged code takes a reference to them and calls them after `MRK3LINK_Open` returns. Otherwise the garbage collector is liable to collect them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've got it now :)